# Splitting the array in python on the based of position

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a array in python as:

```
newarray=['Title',
 'Salary USD',
 'Equity %',
 'Equity USD',
 'Work location',
 'Years of Experience',
 'Years at Startup',
 'Stage',
 'Size',
 'Staff electrical engineer',
 '$226,000',
 '0.002%',
 '$650,000',
 'San Francisco',
 '8.0',
 '3.0',
 'Series H',
 '1001-5000 employees',
 'Sales development representative',
 '$95,000',
 '0.0%',
 '-',
 'Remote',
 '1.0',
 '1.0',
 'Series H',
 '1001-5000 employees',
 'Product manager',
 '$286,000',
 '0.002%',
 '$1,460,000',
 'Remote US',
 '10.0',
 '1.0',
 'Series H',
 '1001-5000 employees',
 'Data analytics manager',
 '$190,000',
 '0.01%',
 '$126,000',
 'Remote',
 '6.0',
 '4.0',
 'Series H',
 '201-500 employees']
```

There are thousands of data in this newarray. I have only illustrated some.After count of every `9` elements ,I want them in **subarray**.I just want split the inner data and put it into `subarray`. My expected output is:

```
newarray=[['Title',
 'Salary USD',
 'Equity %',
 'Equity USD',
 'Work location',
 'Years of Experience',
 'Years at Startup',
 'Stage',
 'Size'],
 ['Staff electrical engineer',
 '$226,000',
 '0.002%',
 '$650,000',
 'San Francisco',
 '8.0',
 '3.0',
 'Series H',
 '1001-5000 employees'],
['Sales development representative',
 '$95,000',
 '0.0%',
 '-',
 'Remote',
 '1.0',
 '1.0',
 'Series H',
 '1001-5000 employees'],
 ['Product manager',
 '$286,000',
 '0.002%',
 '$1,460,000',
 'Remote US',
 '10.0',
 '1.0',
 'Series H',
 '1001-5000 employees'],
 ['Data analytics manager',
 '$190,000',
 '0.01%',
 '$126,000',
 'Remote',
 '6.0',
 '4.0',
 'Series H',
 '201-500 employees']]
```

I just want to make subarray of each 9 items.

I tried using splitting using from index 0 to 8 but it didn't worked:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array(newarray)
newarray= np.array_split(newarray, 8)
print(newarray)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want a single 2D array? Then [`reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

```
out = arr.reshape((-1,9))
```

*NB. be careful, `reshape` requires that you have a multiple of the dimensions, here you need n*9 items in the initial array.*

output:

```
array([['Title', 'Salary USD', 'Equity %', 'Equity USD', 'Work location',
        'Years of Experience', 'Years at Startup', 'Stage', 'Size'],
       ['Staff electrical engineer', '$226,000', '0.002%', '$650,000',
        'San Francisco', '8.0', '3.0', 'Series H', '1001-5000 employees'],
       ['Sales development representative', '$95,000', '0.0%', '-',
        'Remote', '1.0', '1.0', 'Series H', '1001-5000 employees'],
       ['Product manager', '$286,000', '0.002%', '$1,460,000',
        'Remote US', '10.0', '1.0', 'Series H', '1001-5000 employees'],
       ['Data analytics manager', '$190,000', '0.01%', '$126,000',
        'Remote', '6.0', '4.0', 'Series H', '201-500 employees']],
      dtype='<U32')
```

Comment: @Dikshit `arr` is a numpy array according to your code: `arr = np.array(newarray)`

Comment: hi @mozway thank you it worked will tick your ans. can you explain me what it's doing?

Comment: @DikshitKarki it is adding a new dimension here, I updated the answer with a link to the documentation

Answer (score 0):

```
res = [newarray[x:x+9] for x in range(0, len(newarray), 9)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it:

```
n = len(newarray)//9

print([newarray[i::n] for i in range(n)])
```